# Make a remote printer available as a local printer - Google Cloud Print or Remote Printing without Dialogue box

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printer, remote, network-printer

I want to send a print job to a remote printer in an office in another city. I can achieve this using Google Cloud Print. However, every time I print I have to select my printer from the Google Cloud Print dialogue box. This is not practical when having several print jobs or when having automated print jobs.

I am interested in knowing if there is a way to enable Google Cloud Print or any other solution, to automatically print to a designated printer.

Alternatively, would love to know if there is a way to add the remote (office) printer as a local printer and print to this printer like any other local printer.

Answer (score 0):

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver is what is needed to add the cloud print printer as a local printer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Due to the link leading to a software download if the link becomes invalid there is little that I can add to the answer that would not become invalid at the same time anyways.